# Объединение нескольких изображений с одного ракурса в одно

Tags: android, изображения

Помогите найти библиотеку или решение, чтобы получить эффект как на картинке ниже. То есть, чтобы я взял несколько фоток с одного ракурса и смог объединить их все в одну фотографию:

[image]

Comment: This site is for questions on russian language only. You can either translate your question on russian language or ask it at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: See this question on English SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747989/using-java-s-marvin-framework-with-android

Comment: @Alex перевел на русский)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298646/how-to-merge-images-and-impose-on-each-other